# AFNetworking construct JSON parameters using nested NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking for sending some JSON data to a server using HTTP POST. AFNetworking is configured using `setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding`.
So I build my request parameters like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* users = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSDictionary *localEntity in SOMECOREDATAENTITIES)
        {
            // create a new dict. "user"
            NSMutableDictionary* user = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            // add basic parameters for our user
            [user setValue:[localEntity valueForKey:@"firstname"] forKey:@"first_name"];
            [user setValue:[localEntity valueForKey:@"lastname"] forKey:@"last_name"];

            //one level down: create a new dict. and give it some key-value pairs
            NSMutableDictionary* device = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [device setValue:localEntity[@"imei"] forKey:@"device_imei"];
            // add the new dict. to the user
            [user setValue:device forKey:@"device"];

            //two levels down:  create a new array and add multiple dict. to it
            NSMutableDictionary* oEntitys = localEntity[@"orders"];
            NSMutableArray* orders = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSDictionary *orderEntity in oEntitys)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary* order = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [order setValue:[orderEntity valueForKey:@"orderID"] forKey:@"order_id"];
                [orders addObject:order];
            }
            // add the array containing multiple NSDictionarys to the user dict.
            [user setValue:orders forKey:@"orders"];

            // finally add our user to the users dict.
            [users addObject:user];
        }

        // we add our users dict to the AFNetworking parameters
        [params setValue:users forKey:@"users"];
        // we add some more settings to the AFNetworking parameters
        [params setValue:@"SOMEVALUE" forKey:@"SOMEKEY"];
```

as you see, we got nearly everything in here: NSDictionary with some key-value pairs but also nested NSDictionary objects and NSArrays nested within NSDictrionaries.
When looking at the network traffic send, I see that a JSON object is send that looks like this: 
[image: NSDictionary is not resolved correctly to JSON format]

**NOTE: The data send is a key:users with a value:"object". I'm not able to look into that "object" since in fact it is no object, just a string named "object"! That's the problem here.**

However, the AFNetworking setup seems fine (I'm able to drill down the "users"-object) - it's just a problem with the NSDictionary I guess - because if I use something like this for testing:

```
params = @{@"users":
            @{
                   firstname: @"SOMENAMEVALUE",
                   lastname: @"SOMENAMEVALUE"
            },
           @"SOMEKEY": @"SOMEVALUE"]
         };
```

then the traffic I sniff looks right:

[image: Resolved correctly]

What am I missing here?

Comment: In order to get more info, you might serialize your "users" dictionary with NSJSONSerialization with "pretty print" option, convert that UTF-8 data to a NSString an print it to the console. That way you can confirm that your JSON data input is actually what you expect. Otherwise, why not sending JSON text per a simple POST request whose headers are configured appropriately? I mean, why would one ever realy need the overly fancy feature `setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding` at all?

Comment: You can use AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger to log your outgoing requests: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger.  But I think this is an issue with your dictionaries, since AFNetworking doesn't do anything fancy with the `parameters` dictionary - just runs it through NSJSONSerialization.  Have you set a breakpoint at the end and typed `po params` into the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger. Ideed what I see is that the users object is empty: `{"users":{},"SOMEKEY":"SOMEVALUE"}`. I just don't know why the NSArray / NSDictionary are not added correctly.

Comment: Turns out there is nothing wrong with my code. I simply had a mistake in my core data request which returned NULL - doh. Anyway: the AFNetworkingLogger hint helped me hunting it down. Thank!